# operator overload like syntax in C using the preprocessor

Tags: c, operator-overloading, c-preprocessor

Would it be a good practice to use the following preprocessor trick in a code with full of vector calculations? On the one hand it pollutes the namespace using generic identifiers (mul,add,...) and smells like a dirty hack, but on the other hand it may makes complex expressions more readable.
Are there any other pros/cons?

```
typedef struct { double x,y; } vector;
vector vector_add(vector v0, vector v1);
double vector_mul(vector v0, vector v1);
...
#define _(a) opf(a)
#define mul ,mul,
#define add ,add,
...
#define opf(a,o,b) vector_##o((a),(b))

void example(void)
{
  vector a, b, c;
  double d;

  d = _( _(a add b) mul c);

  // equivalent without the macros:
  d = vector_mul(vector_add(a,b),c);
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to use C++?  BTW, the second example is waaaay more readable.

Comment: Yes, it's an existing C project. I'm not sure about the readability. Specially for longer expressions.

Comment: This would severely affect the maintainability of the code and for a very tiny readability gain (and that's very arguable too). Is infix notation really that special? Besides, I personally think that operator overloading is a questionable idea in most languages.

Comment: If you think `vector_mul` is too long, maybe just `#define vmul vector_mul`. But don't go trying to change the syntax of C just to gain a bit of readability, because other people who read the code will almost certainly have a harder time understanding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a good idea (in my opinion, of course).

Assuming I know the C language reasonably well, if I see a line of code like:

```
d = vector_mul(vector_add(a,b),c);
```

I have a pretty good idea what it does. I need to look at the types of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, and the declarations of the functions, to be sure, but even without that I can safely assume it's doing a vector addition and a vector multiplication.

On the other hand, if I see:

```
d = _( _(a add b) mul c);
```

I'll likely have no clue what it's doing until I first track down the macro definitions, and then either study them until I understand your new syntax, or just expand them myself to ordinary C code that I can understand. Of course *you* know what your syntax means, and that's fine if you're the only person reading the code, but anyone else will wonder what the underscores are for.

And that's assuming I realize that you're using macros. Macro names are conventionally written in all-caps. Using `ADD` and `MUL` would be an improvement, but IMHO not enough to override the other disadvantages.

A personal anecdote: Many years ago, when I was first learning C, I thought that this:

```
#define EVER ;;

...

for (EVER) {
    /* ... */
}
```

was very clever. I still think it's very clever; I just no longer think it's a good idea.

Comment: +1: I figure out that reading your code it would be as reading nice literature. I feel that your advices here (in the sense of well-readable code) were very good.